# Extending an existing web2py database

Tags: python, web2py

I have an existing web2py application.  Now I need to create a new registration form using a db Table that includes a Field that requires a Row from a different Table.

This should be similar to what you commonly see with Country Fields in registration forms, except I want people to be able to add values to the 'Country' Table if the value doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a small improvement to the previous response:

```
# create auth
auth = Auth(db)
# create the country table
db.define_table('country',
                Field('name'),
                Field('desc'),
                format = '%(name)s')
# say you want to add it to auth_user table (not yet created)
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']=[Field('country','reference country')]
# ask auth to make the auth tables, including auth_user
auth.define_tables()
```

JMax is right. We are more responsive on the web2py mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Massimo, I appreciate your improvement :) I'll check out the Google Group too, thanks.

Comment: Just tried doing this, but I'm getting the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Plumber'.

This is my code:

`db.define_table(auth.settings.table_user_name,
                Field('title', db.title),
                format='%(name)s',
                )
db.define_table('title',
                Field('name'),
                format='%(name)s'
               )`

So confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a one to many relation (cf. the [book](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#One-to-Many-Relation)):

```
db.define_table('country',
                Field('name'),
                Field('desc'))

db.define_table('user',
                Field('name'),
                Field('origin'), db.country))
```

Btw, you can ask your questions on the [web2py Googlegroup](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py) where Massimo will probably be more reactive

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea it was called a one to many relation :)